# Getting debug info of a java object

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm debugging a piece of code in Eclipse. When I try to get the info of an object I'm getting a lot of null values in the info window (Ctrl+Shift+i), but it shows the right values at the bottom of the same window. Pic of the issue below:

[image: Ctrl+Shift+i window]

Request by: user7294900

[image]

Request by: howlger

[image]

[image]

Can you tell me why this is happen? Is this the right behaviour?

Comment: Can you show how the `toString()` method printing the id?

Comment: Added a pic. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Yes, that might be the right behavior if `toString()` gets the ID from somewhere else if the field `id` is `null`. So please show the code of `PropuestaGasto`'s `toString()` method.

Comment: Question edited to show it :)